# Convert StringBuffer encryption to int

Tags: java, stringbuffer

So I have a basic encryptor that after it decrypts, I want to convert the string of numbers in that file to an int.

```
public class Encryption {

//Basic Encryptor/Decryptor
public Encryption() throws IOException {
    StringBuffer num = new StringBuffer("100");
    encrypt(num);

    File f = new File("C:\\fun\\a");
    if(f.mkdirs()) {
    File f2 = new File(f,"b.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f2);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
    bw.write(num.toString());
    bw.close();

    Scanner s = new Scanner(f2);
    String aaa = new String(s.nextLine());
    StringBuffer bbb = new StringBuffer(aaa);
    decrypt(bbb);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(aaa.toString());

    System.out.println(b);



    }

}

//ENCRYPTOR
public static void encrypt(StringBuffer word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = (int)word.charAt(i);
        temp = temp * 9;
        word.setCharAt(i, (char)temp);
    }
}

//DECRYPTOR
public static void decrypt(StringBuffer word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        temp = (int)word.charAt(i);
        temp = temp / 9;
        word.setCharAt(i, (char)temp);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Encryption e = new Encryption();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  }
```

I tried to convert the string buffer to a string then an int. When I check the file, it is still encrypted and the console has an error decrypting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "???"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Encryptor.Encryption.<init>(Encryption.java:28)
at Encryptor.Encryption.main(Encryption.java:62)
```

Which points to `int b = Integer.parseInt(aaa.toString());`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your only problem is that you're trying to parse the contents of the `aaa` StringBuffer.  The `aaa` StringBuffer still contains the encrypted contents.  You're passing the `bbb` buffer to the decrypt method, so that is the buffer you should attempt to parse into an int:

`int b = Integer.parseInt(bbb.toString());`

Comment: It still throws an exception and cannot decrypt

Comment: Can you update your source in the question to what you have now?  After changing the line mentioned in my answer, the program prints out '100'.

Comment: did you change just that one line?

Comment: Yes, that one line change was the only modification I made. Can you confirm that you're recompiling? That's the only thing coming to mind that would cause your program to still not decrypt and print the value.

Comment: Here is a gif what I'm doing: http://i.imgur.com/rte8ugV.gif         EDIT: You ran the whole program with the file i/o part as well?

Comment: It looks like the contents of your encrypted buffer are not being written or created successfully. The UTF encoded characters should be written to the txt file, but instead the unknown character representation (?) is being written. My txt file contents are "ƹưư". I'm not sure why you're seeing that behavior.